# Ratio of Standard Deviations from a Normal Distribution to an F Distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, f-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

Apologies if the title is confusing, I couldn't think of a more apt title.

I have that $W_i$s are iid $N(\mu_a,\sigma_a^2)$ and independent of $Z_i$s which are iid $N(\mu_b,\sigma_b^2)$. This means

$$
\frac{\frac{1}{k-1}\sum_{i=1}^k(W_i-\bar{W}_k)}{\sigma_a^2}\stackrel{d}{=}\frac{\chi_{k-1}^2}{k-1} \\
\frac{\frac{1}{j-1}\sum_{i=1}^j(Z_i-\bar{Z}_j)}{\sigma_b^2}\stackrel{d}{=}\frac{\chi_{j-1}^2}{j-1}
$$

From here, I am trying to find a 90% confidence interval for $\sigma_a/\sigma_b$.

So far I have the following

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sigma_a^2}{\sigma_b^2}
=\frac{\frac{(k-1)\hat{_\mu}_{w,k-1}}{\chi_{k-1}^2}}{\frac{(j-1)\hat{_\mu}_{z,j-1}}{\chi_{j-1}^2}}
&=\frac{(k-1)\hat{_\mu}_{w,k-1}\chi_{j-1}^2}{(j-1)\hat{_\mu}_{z,j-1}\chi_{k-1}^2} \\
&=\bigg[\frac{(k-1)}{\chi_{w,k-1}^2}\bigg]\bigg[\frac{\chi_{z,j-1}^2}{(j-1)}\bigg]\bigg[\frac{\hat{_\mu}_{w,k-1}}{\hat{_\mu}_{z,j-1}}\bigg] \\
&=\bigg[\frac{\chi_{z,j-1}^2/(j-1)}{\chi_{w,k-1}^2/(k-1)}\bigg]\bigg[\frac{\hat{_\mu}_{w,k-1}}{\hat{_\mu}_{z,j-1}}\bigg] \\
&=\bigg[\frac{\hat{_\mu}_{w,k-1}}{\hat{_\mu}_{z,j-1}}\bigg]F_{k-1,j-1}
\end{align}
$$
where $F_{k-1,j-1}$ is an F distribution with degrees of freedom $k-1$ and $j-1$.

Should I be able to simplify this further? I just believe that attempting to find the standard deviation of the square root of this in it's current state would be very convoluted.

Comment: You don't have an interval there yet. You'll need to clearly identify the pivotal quantity, construct an interval for that and back out an interval for the ratio of variances (and hence for the principal square root of that).

Comment: @Glen_b I apologize. I know I don't have an interval yet, but I thought what I needed to do was determine the distribution for $\sigma_a/\sigma_b$, then the variance/standard deviation of it, and ultimately use that standard deviation to construct the confidence interval. Should I be making confidence intervals for $W$ and $Z$ instead and backing out from there? Thanks!

Comment: You should not be making intervals for W and Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the notation with $\hat \mu$'s in your question.
For normal data, the sample mean and sample standard deviation are
independent random variables, so a CI for the ratio of standard deviations does not
need to take account of estimates of the population means.

Consider the following simulated data and the results from `var.test` with a
**95%** confidence interval (CI) using the data.

```
set.seed(928)
w = rnorm(51, 100, 10)
z = rnorm(61, 10,  20)
var.test(w,z, conf.int=T)$conf.int
[1] 0.1113846 0.3256269
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

Thus a **95%** CI for $\tau = \sigma_w^2/\sigma_z^2$ is $(0.111, 0.326),$
which does contain the true value of $\tau = 10^2/20^2 = 0.25.$

Denote the ratio of the *sample variances* as $R = S_w^2/S_z^2.$
Then $R/\tau \sim \mathsf{F}(n_w-1, n_z-1).$ Let $L$ and $U$ cut probability
0.025 from the lower and upper tails, respectively, of this distribution.
Then

$$P(L \le R/\tau \le U) = P(R/U \le \tau \le R/L) = 0.05.$$

So with exactly the same data as above, we can get a 95% CI for $\tau$ in R as follows, which agrees with the output from `var.test`.

```
R = var(w)/var(z)
R/qf(c(.975,.025), 50, 60)
[1] 0.1113846 0.3256269
```

I will leave it to you to find a **90%** CI for the ratio of population
**standard deviations.**

*Note:* (1) The following simulation in R illustrates the F-distribution used above.

```
set.seed(2019)
r = replicate(10^6, var(rnorm(51,100,10))/var(rnorm(61,10,20)) )
f = 4*r
hist(f, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="Simulated F(50,60) with Density")
 curve(df(x, 50, 60), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]

(2) The following simulation illustrates the stochastic independence
of $A=\bar X$ and $S$ for normal data $(r \approx 0),$ but not for
exponential data $(r \approx 0.77)$ nor for data from $\mathsf{Beta}(.1,.1).$ In the latter case, $r \approx 0,$ but independence obviously does not hold. [In each scatterplot, each of 50,000 plotted points shows $A$ and $X$ for one sample of size five.]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this response, it has cleared up a lot for me.

I apologize, I screwed up in my main post and called $\hat{\mu}_k = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^k(W_i-\bar{W}_k)$. I'll fix that as soon as I can.

In the mean time, I am unsure of how you come to come to $R/\tau=F(n_w-1, n_z-1)$. Is there a typo in the question I have where $\frac{\frac{1}{k-1}\sum_{i=1}^k(W_i-\bar{W}_k)}{\sigma_a^2}\stackrel{d}{=}\frac{\chi_{k-1}^2}{k-1}$ should actually be $\frac{\frac{1}{k-1}\sum_{i=1}^k(W_i-\bar{W}_k)^2}{\sigma_a^2}\stackrel{d}{=}\frac{\chi_{k-1}^2}{k-1}$?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this typo. For sample variance you need ${}^2$. // If you untangle the notation, I hope you can see that $R/\tau$ follows the definition of F-dist'n [which Note(1) addresses]. // $R$ is ratio of sample variances (has nothing to do with correlation), sometimes denoted $F,$ but I wanted to avoid confusion btw random variable $F$ and dist'n $\mathsf{F}.$ // My displayed eqn shows the 'pivot' required to get CI. // Typo of my own: In my first block of  R code, I just restored missing line `var.test(w,z, conf.int=T)$conf.int`.

Comment: OK, so I am using $\frac{\frac{1}{k-1}\sum_{i=1}^k(W_i-\bar{W}_k)^2}{\sigma_a^2}\stackrel{d}{=}\frac{\chi_{k-1}^2}{k-1}$ and trying to work towards your $R/\tau \sim F(n_w - 1, m_z - 1)$, but I end up with $\tau \sim RF(n_w - 1, m_z - 1)$ when I calculate $\sigma_a^2/\sigma_b^2$ by substituting in ${\sigma_a^2}\stackrel{d}{=}\frac{(k-1)\frac{1}{k-1}\sum_{i=1}^k(W_i-\bar{W}_k)^2}{\chi_{k-1}^2}$

Comment: ^ and the corresponding $\sigma_b^2$

Comment: Please review the idea of a 'pivot' and look at my displayed equation.

Comment: Maybe I'm just misunderstanding, but it looks like it might just be flipped since I screwed up my notation again and actually get $\tau \sim RF(m_z-1,n_w-1)$